# to count or to 'leave' in a combination quiz

Tags: combinatorics

A colleague asked me to solve this problem: In how many ways can a committee of 6 people be chosen from 8 men and 4 women; if at least there are twice as many men as women.

My solution: this of course mean could be twice,  three, ...... times as many men as women and so on. I argue that a case of 6men and 0 women is to be counted! He refuses!

I thought we should, please 'separate' us!

Comment: A committee of $6$ men and $0$ women clearly passes the test, since $6≥2\times 0$.    I don't see any controversy.

Comment: This is it! we only need men to be more so there can be zero women, he argues there must be a woman!